# Estimating likelihood of survey attrition relative to treatment

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a panel survey data where each row represents an individual, their interview date, and labor market status during that period. However, it's an unbalanced panel data where some observations appear more than others (i.e. because some individuals stopped responding to the survey's organizers). Data was collected on individuals before and after some observations were randomly given  a cash assistance benefit.

*I am interested in knowing whether some individuals stopped responding to our survey specifically after they received the cash benefit (i.e. the treatment date which is on 2019-09-03)?*
In other words, I am interested in testing the probability of leaving the survey relative to the "date" variable but I am not sure how to do that.

Here is a data example. For instance, we can see that some individuals like Cartman who received treatment in Sept 2019 stopped responding to the survey in following years and thus their job market status is recorded as "N/A"
Other observations in the control group like Mackey who did not receive the treatment continued responding to the survey in the following years.

```
individual    date        labor_status        cash_ benefit
Kenny       2018-09-02.   unemployed          0         
Kenny      2019-09-03.    unemployed          1      
Kenny      2020-09-07.    employed            1  
Kenny     2021-09-13.      employed           1                          
Cartman   2018-09-03.     unemployed          0     
Cartman  2019-09-06.      unemployed          1    
Cartman  2020-09-08.      N/A                 1
Cartman  2021-09-08.      N/A                 1
Mackey   2018-09-03.      employed            0  
Mackey   2019-09-04.      unemployed          0    
Mackey  2020-09-08.       employed            0
Mackey  2021-09-13.       employed            0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re looking to test this statistically, you should ask on Cross Validated. But if you just want the probability of dropout after 2019 conditional on receiving benefit:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dat %>%
  group_by(individual) %>%
  summarize(
    benefit = any(cash_benefit == 1),
    dropout_after_2019 = all(
      year(date) < 2019 |
      (year(date) == 2019 & !is.na(labor_status)) |
      is.na(labor_status)
    )
  ) %>%
  group_by(benefit) %>%
  summarize(p_dropout_after_2019 = mean(dropout_after_2019))
```

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  benefit p_dropout_after_2019
  <lgl>                  <dbl>
1 FALSE                    0  
2 TRUE                     0.5
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful! But I am more interested in comparing the probability of attrition between two groups (i.e. treatment and control groups), and I wonder if I can estimate the relative probability, rather than within group probability.

Comment: @maldini1992 You can get the [relative risk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_risk) of dropout after the benefit date in the treatment vs. control group by dividing the treatment group probability by the control group probability -- in this case `0.5 / 0` which is undefined, but presumably would work with your full data. Or you can get the [odds ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_ratio) as `(0.5 / (1 - 0.5)) / (0 / (1 - 0))` (which is also undefined in the example data).

Comment: Thanks a lot!
In my case, the treatment group has a 0.72 probability compared to 0.28, so I believe the relative risk is .72/.28 ~2.51, which means treatment individuals were 2.5 times as likely to drop post-treatment.